# My Question is about Antd Pagination control index when i want to use

Tags: antd

when i  create Pagination this label  and  i  want  to  control  it  when  i  send  ajax  and  then  success callback function  and  then  change index

i tried  use onchange function  and then  change  current  the  num  but  still stay  current page  not  use

Table label   have    pagination

--like so

```
                                pagination={{
                                    total: total,
                                    pageSize: limit,
                           /*         onChange(current) {
                                        dispatch({
                                            type: '@LotteryBetRecord/turning',
                                            payload: {
                                                post: that.getSearchParames(),
                                                pageSize: limit,
                                                current: current - 1
                                            }
                                        })
                                    },*/
                                    onChange:(current,limit)=>{
                                        that.onChange.bind(this,current,limit)
                                    },
                                    showTotal: function () {
                                        return `共${total}条记录`
                                    }
                                }}
                            />



                    onConfirm={() => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: 'operational/betting',
                            payload: {
                                blist: JSON.stringify(betListValue),
                                callback: (res) => {
                                    if (res.error === 0) {
                                        message.success('success')
                                        that.search()
                                        that.onChange(2,10)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        })
                    }}


onChange(current,limit){
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch({
        type: '@LotteryBetRecord/turning',
        payload: {
            post: this.getSearchParames(),
            pageSize: limit,
            current: current - 1
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in this component in version 3.13.2. The related issue is here; https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14875.  When you pass second page, your fill your datasource but your second page seems empty, and there is still only one page. Check newer version or you can use below workaround;

```
dataSource={[...Array.from({length: (current - 1) * pageSize}), ...dataSource]}
```